# Is there a way to make pink peppercorns properly grindable in a pepper mill?

Tags: pepper

Dried pink peppercorns are softer than their black and white cousins and have skins that come off easily. Consequently they clog up the grinding mechanism in my mill. If the setting is coarse enough for them to come out at all they come out whole or in very big pieces. Is there something I can do to them to prevent this from happening? If not, what is the best way to dispense them?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly this isn't something I've thought about before, as when ever I've used pink peppercorns they've been mixed with black, green and white ones. Which I assume help's dry out the softer and wetter pink corns stopping the grinder from clogging.

Moving forward my first and main suggestion would be to treat it like any other spice, and use a pestle and mortar. Asides from definitely not clogging with this method, you will also have much greater control over how fine/coarse the result is.

Another possibility would be a [spice grinder](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Spice%20grinder) though, probably no use for small amounts.

---

On a side note:

Apparently pink peppercorns can affect persons who are allergic to tree nuts.

They are also deemed as a toxic by the FDA, although not at a life threatening level

https://nutgourmet.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/warning-pretty-pink-peppercorns-can-be-dangerous/